# web api with entity framework or ado.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, angularjs, entity-framework, architecture

We have web application developed in Asp.net 3.5 with 3 tier architecture. At that time we have used ADO.net and stored procedure. Now we planning to convert it into SPA using AngularJS and asp.net Web API. We are confused whether to go with Entity framework or ADO.net. As we are having stored procedures for CRUD operations will it be beneficial to use Entity framework or should we go ADO.net way.
Please give suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a WebAPI project with the wizard it can generate CRUD based on EF. Actually it's a good practice to insert a View Model between DAL/EF Entities and web services so you need a little work (i.e. creating VM and using a mapper like automapper). After that no more work on WebAPI project.

Communication between WebAPI project and AngularJS is "free" (WebAPI uses JSON).

About your project and using ADO I don't know, if it works why change it. But if you have a good reason to work hard on the server could be a good time to change ADO with EF.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I am changing it as I want this application should work on any device and should be lightweight. So for device independent application I think  WebApi and angularjs is good option.